# In VBA for Word, How can I use the Find method on a hyperlink address?

Tags: vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I have 700+ links in a document, and I want to scan the hyperlink addresses with a certain simple regex using the `.Find` method. Unfortunately, everything I try limits the Find to the displayed text rather than the actual hyperlink address.

Any help would be appreciated.
This is a code snippet that represents what I have now:

```
Set rng = .Hyperlinks(i).Range
Set fnd = rng.Find
```

(The range set in the first line, is unfortunately the displayed text, and not the hyperlink address text.)

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like this should be possible by iteration over the `Hyperlinks` collection, and working with each hyperlink's `Address` property. You won't be able to use the `Range.Find` method for this, but you could still use a regular expressions against the address text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `FieldCode` to make the links visible:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
```

Then you can search for links as same as what you do for texts; This's just an example that I recorded:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = Not ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "https://me.you"
    .Replacement.Text = "https://you.me"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```